# JMX Remote Deployment Architecture

Tags: java, monitoring, jmx

I'm reading up on JMX for the first time, and trying to see if its a feasible solution to a problem we're having on production.

We have an architecture that is *constantly* hitting a remote web service (managed by a different team on their own servers) and requesting data from it (we also cache from this service, but its a sticky problem where caching isn't extremely effective).

We'd like the *ability* to dynamically turn logging on/off at one specific point in the code, right before we hit the web service, where we can see the exact URLs/queries we're sending to the service. If we just blindly set a logging level and logged all web service requests, we'd have *astronomically-large* log files.

JMX seems to be the solution, where we control the logging in this section with a managed bean, and then can set that bean's state (`setLoggingEnabled(boolean)`, etc.) remotely via some manager (probably just basic HTML adaptor).

My questions are all deployment-related:

- If I write the MBean interface and impl, as well as the agent (which register MBeans and the HTML adaptor with the platform MBean server), do I compile, package & deploy those inside my main web application (WAR), or do they have to compile to their own, say, JAR and sit on the JVM beside my application?
- We have a Dev, QA, Demo and Prod envrionment; is it possible to have 1 single HTML adaptor pointing to an MBean server which has different MBeans registered to it, 1 for each environment? It would be nice to have one URL to go to where you can manage beans in different environments
- If the answer to my first question above is that the MBean interface, impl and agent all deploy inside your application, then is it possible to have your JMX-enabled application deployed on one server (say, Demo), but to monitor it from another server?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How you package the MBeans is in great part a matter of portability. Will these specific services have any realistic usefulness outside the scope of this webapp ? If not, I would simply declare your webapp "JMX Manageable" and build it in. Otherwise, componentize the MBeans, put them in a jar, put the jar in the WEB-INF/lib and initialize them using a startup servlet configured in your web.xml.

For the single HTML adaptor, yes it is possible. Think of it as having Dev, QA, Demo and Prod MBeanServers, and then one **Master** MBeanServer. Your HTML Adaptor should render the master. Then you can use the [OpenDMK cascading service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9710003/is-it-possible-with-jmx-to-register-or-show-the-mbeans-form-different-vms-in-one) to register cascades of Dev, QA, Demo and Prod  in the Master. Now you will see all 5 MBeanServer's beans in the HTML adaptor display.

Does that answer your third question ?

Answer (score 0):

`JMX` is a technology used for remote management of your application and for a situation for example when you want to change a configuration without a restart is the most proper use.

But in your case, I don't see why you would need JMX. For example if you use `Log4j` for your logging you could configure a file watchdog and just change logging to the lowest possible level. I.e. to debug. This does not require a restart and IMHO that should have been your initial design in the first place i.e. work arround loggers and levels. Right now, it is not clear what you mean and what happens with `setLoggingEnable`.

In any case, the managed bean is supposed to be deployed with your application and if you are using Spring you are in luck since it offers a really nice integration with `JMX` and you could deploy your spring beans as managed beans.

Finally when you connect to your process you will see the managed beans running for that JVM. So I am not sure what exactly you mean with point 2.

Anyway I hope this helps a little

Comment: In response to your first item, no matter what log level we set log4j to, when it does log, it will log hundreds of thousands, millions, etc. of messages - too much for us to handle, so a log level-based solution is not applicable in our situation

Comment: In response to the 2nd item, let's say we have a demo server at blah.example.com. This server is running Tomcat, which has our WAR file (a web app) deployed to it. Now let's say we configured our WAR's managed beans to use an HTML adaptor so we can monitar/manage them from a web URL. Will that URL be off blah.example.com, or can we set up JMX's monitoring to be served up from some second server, like fizz.example.com?